# Is there a preferred method to handling modal popups and other "hidden" html when building web apps in a MVC framework?

Tags: javascript, html, model-view-controller

In many cases, we have things like modal popups with specific messages to users like "Are you sure you want to do that...", "Is asdf@asdf really your email...", etc.  The way we have been handling it right now is that we have the html for the popup in the included .js file.  Then of course the view file includes that .js.  But it feels like that isn't the ideal way to organize the code.

Keeping with an MVC architecture, how should this kind of code be organized?  Should it be placed in the View directly and hidden/revealed via javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're not MVC, but we do this by having controls. [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wt3k2fyw.aspx)

I'm sure there's an MVC equivalent, or you might even be able to use `ascx` in MVC, not entirely sure.